# Can't start jupyter notebook on ubuntu 18.04.3 after installed it

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm using python3 and I installed jupyter-notebook running:
`$ sudo apt install jupyter-notebook`

Now on start when I type "jupyter-notebook" I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('notebook==5.2.2', 'console_scripts', 'jupyter-notebook')()
  File "/home/helias/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/helias/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/helias/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/helias/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = import(self.module_name, fromlist=['name'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 43, in <module>
    ioloop.install()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/ioloop.py", line 210, in install
    assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \
AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this installing/updating the library **pyzmq**, using pip:

`pip3 install pyzmq`

Note: use just `pip` if you are using Python2.

If you are using `conda`, you can run:

`conda install -c anaconda pyzmq`

Comment: I think install jupyter through conda or pip is better.